# for each unique value in column, how do i loop through the dataframe with specific time period?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I have a data column df.HH with unique values between 1-48, a datetime index of df.Datetime and a df.price column

I would like to loop each unique value of df.HH to pick out only the last 10 mins of price activity

i.e. df.last("10min") would just be the last 10 min of the whole dataset and i would like the last 10 min of each unique HH

so i tried to run

```
 dfs=[]
for i in UK_Trades["HH"].unique():
    df_i = UK_Trades.last("10min")
    dfs.append(df_i.copy())

dfs
```

But it doesnt do the trick, any comment welcomed
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = UK_Trades.groupby('HH', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.last('10min'))
```

Another idea is get last value per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and compare last `10min` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = UK_Trades.reset_index().groupby('HH')['index'].transform('last')
mask = (UK_Trades.index > s - pd.Timedelta('10min')) & (UK_Trades.index <=s)

df = UK_Trades[mask]
```

Comment: do you have other method without using lambda?